# Get largest percentage, output the value associated with it, not the percentage

Tags: mysql

I need this query to display the most commonly entered price. To do this, I need to find the largest percentage of each price submitted, and display that price associated with the percentage as the accepted value of the ItemID. **I do not need the percentage itself to be returned.**

Here is an example of the data I'll be dealing with:

```
+--------+-------+
| ItemID | Price |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 15    |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 15    |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 15    |
+--------+-------+
| 14     | 27    |
+--------+-------+
| 14     | 27    |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 35    |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 35    |
+--------+-------+
| 14     | 27    |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 15    |
+--------+-------+
```

From that you get:

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| ItemID | Price | Percentage |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 12     | 15    | 66.6%      |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 12     | 35    | 33.3%      |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 14     | 27    | 100%       |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

**And finally, this is what I need for my output**:

So for example; If a query for item 12 is requested, return this:

```
+--------+-------+
| ItemID | Price |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 15    |
+--------+-------+
```

If a query for ItemID 14 is requested:

```
+--------+-------+
| ItemID | Price |
+--------+-------+
| 14     | 27    |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT ItemID, Price FROM Table
WHERE ItemID = 12
GROUP BY Price
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Output should be:

```
+--------+-------+
| ItemID | Price |
+--------+-------+
| 12     | 15    |
+--------+-------+
```

Note that you don't actually need to compute the percentage for which each price occurs, because finding the price which occurs the most often is sufficient.